# Intermittent httplib error when using selenium 2.47 with python

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, httplib

I'm using Selenium 2.47 to drive Firefox 28.0 to do some basic purchase checks on an in-app purchase platform. The tests fail around 30% of the time due to the following

```
File "/path/Steps/do_something.py", line 19, in main
selenium_tearDown.tearDown(driver)
File "path/selenium_tearDown.py", line 7, in tearDown
driver.quit()
File "usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 87, in quit
RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
File "usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 483, in quit
self.execute(Command.QUIT)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 199, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/atvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in     execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 425, in _request
self._conn.request(method, parsed_url.path, body, headers)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 973, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1001, in _send_request
self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 871, in putrequest
raise CannotSendRequest()
CannotSendRequest
```

The test is trying to close a browser window, but fails to do so.

This error only occurs when the tests are run on our Jenkins machines, whereby when I them locally I do not get the same fault. Both environments are bootstrapped to be identical, and run the same versions of selenium, firefox, etc.

It appears this issue has occurred in previous versions of selenium, but should have been fixed in 2.39. I have tried rolling back to 2.39 however we use custom browser profiles that then start failing.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest selenium and firefox? (2.49 and 43 respectively)

Comment: Hi Alecxe - yes I have and it introduced issues with our firefox profiles, so we went back to what we knew was stable (2.47 with 28)

Comment: try `driver.exit()` method instead of `driver.quit()`

Comment: Hi @Andersson, afraid driver has no method exit(), only driver.close() and driver.quit(), both of which return the same http error

Comment: It appears this is a bug lodged with selenium. FWIW it is possible to swallow the exception using the python firefox bindings: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1411